# How briny should the water be when soaking broccoli to remove bugs?

Tags: vegetables, soaking

I've seen advice to drop homegrown broccoli in a pot of salted water for a while so the bugs come out.

What's the right salt:water ratio and how long should I soak?

Comment: Gross, just gross. :)

Comment: @hobodave - It's not *that* gross... think about what they might be doing to grocery store broccoli to keep the bugs off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only number I've ever heard was 4-6 teaspoons of salt per gallon of water, but that's just something a friend told me, they might've made it up.  I've never actually seen any bugs on broccoli - organic or otherwise - so when I wash it I usually just shake in about 1/2 tsp into the bowl.

EDIT: [Here's a site that says 1 tsp per quart.](http://www.asianhomerecipe.com/cooking_tips/broccoli-preparing.php)

Answer (score 5):

Ah... I remember doing this growing up. Usually used a small handful of table salt in a sink full of water, and the worms would be floating on the top after about 5-10 minutes.

*Most* of the worms.

Sorry I can't give you a more precise ratio; I actually suspect soaking in water does more good than the salt - the worms don't swim.

At least, *most* of them don't.

Comment: Re: *most* - Extra protein!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter.  Salt is cheap, throw a good handful in.
Broccoli won't absorb salt, so any brine will remain on the surface. Just rinse it off.

I've found the same with eggplant -- it's impossible to oversalt if you rinse it off.

Answer (score 2):

1 tsp to 1 quart water for five minutes. Do not over-salt as the bugs just roll into balls and don't come out at all. But if you salt lightly, they are lightly irritated and float to the surface.